webpage scrolls left on mobile view but not desktop view
i'm having problems with my website that seems to scroll to the left on mobile view (home page)
ive checked the elements if there is an overlap but everything seems ok, yet it still scrolls to the right
i use elementor and wordpress to build the website
https://q6academy.com/
does anyone know why this is happening?
ive checked the elements on my page to see if there is an overlap but everything seems ok, yet it still scrolls to the right

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

Also, please read why offsite links are not good



.container, .edublink-container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}



Add this code on your custom css. it will solve the scroll issue on your mobile view,
I tested on your website, it works perfectly,
If its works for you accept as the answer.

hi again my friend! can i use the same code to recttify the same issue on www.digitaldesigns.live as i cant seem to rectify the issue on mobile view for that one page -

Need to check the css class name. I think so it's defer for the digitaldesigns website.
